# Difference between injection using @inject and applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, cdi

Is there any difference in how Spring injects the referenced bean between

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    @Named("myNiceBean")
    private MyBean bean;
    public MyBean getBean() { return bean; }
    public void setBean(MyBean bean) { this.bean = bean; }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="myNiceBean" class="com.exemple.DummyBean" />
```

AND

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyBean bean;
    public MyBean getBean() { return bean; }
    public void setBean(MyBean bean) { this.bean = bean; }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="myNiceBean" class="com.exemple.DummyBean" />
<bean id="myClass" class="com.exemple.MyClass">
    <property name="bean" ref="myNiceBean"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example simply uses the annotated approach to inject the bean. In fact, there is no need for the setter and getter methods, `Spring` will take care of this. In the second (manual) injection example, the setter & getter methods *are* required.